# Sudden increase in rpm when my car is in motion

Tags: chevrolet, rpm, cng

I have chevorlet Enjoy purchased one year ago andgot it converted to CNG.

Nowadays my car is giving problem of increase in rpm during running. It accelarates automatically but comes back to normal after few seconds.  This problem is mainly observed in 2nd gear.

When we referred this problem to our CNG fitted company they said the IC valve is to be replaced.  Chevorlet did change the IC valve when noticed problemistic.

Bt then also my problem isnt solved.  Where isthe actual problem.  Chevorlet people say they need to investigate this.

Could u please help?

Answer (score 1):

For what ever reason, if Chevrolet, or thier subsideries say they need to investigate the problem with your vehicle then you should allow this to take place. Chevrolet will know the vehicle better then anyone else, and if the addition of the CNG equipment is at fault they will easily home in on it.